# Use more than one property in React Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm new to React, and I have a question. I'm creating my own button. And I want to do it in an optimized way, including the attributes of the button itself, for example:

`disabled, aria-disabled, type, id`

I want to have access to all button attributes, without manually inserting them in an interface. And along with these attributes, also include the new ones I created, for example:

`loading, buttonSize, variant`

My code in summary is this:

```
export type ButtonProps = {
  icon?: React.ReactElement<HTMLOrSVGElement>;
  loading?: boolean;
}

class Button extends React.Component<ButtonProps> {
  constructor(props: ButtonProps) {
    super(props);
  }

  get classes(): string {
    return classnames(
      CSS_CLASSES.ROOT,
      this.props.theme === 'outline' && CSS_CLASSES.OUTLINE,
      this.props.theme === 'filled' && CSS_CLASSES.FILLED,
      this.props.theme === 'tonal' && CSS_CLASSES.TONAL,
      this.props.size === 'small' && CSS_CLASSES.SMALL,
      this.props.size === 'large' && CSS_CLASSES.LARGE,
      this.props.className
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button></button>
    )
  }
}

const ForwardedElement = React.forwardRef<ButtonProps, HTMLButtonElement> (
  (props: ButtonProps, ref) => <Button {...props}/>
)

export default ForwardedElement;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by changing `ButtonProps` to this:

```
export type interface extends React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>, HTMLButtonElement> {
  icon?: React.ReactElement<HTMLOrSVGElement>;
  loading?: boolean;
}
```

Then in your `render` do this:

```
render() {
  return (
    <button {...this.props} />
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
type MyProps = React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement> & {
   text: string
 }

const MyButton = ({ text, ...props }: MyProps) => {
   return <button {...props}>{text}</button>
 }

export default MyButton
```

Now you can access custom props and properties of a button as well.